# Obtener una lista con el contenido de una columna de un archivo csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Estoy buscando acceder a todos los valores del campo `ddomain` de mi lista y que me cree otra lista nueva con esos valores. Creo que con un `for item in your_list` se podria hacer pero no encuentro la forma.

```
with open("Top20_Media_10-12-17.csv", 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    your_list = list(reader)
    print your_list
[['Category', 'ddomain', 'opportunities', 'impressions', 'fillRate', 'DATA'], [' ', 'App', '69491941', '13720', '0.02', 'OK'], ['Real Site', 'kimcartoon.me', '157036', '650', '0.41', 'OK'], ['Real Site', 'capitalgazette.com', '2380', '450', '18.91', 'OK'], ['Real Site', 'best.io', '18180', '376', '2.07', 'OK'], ['Real Site', 'statsroyale.com', '121269', '373', '0.31', 'OK'], ['Detected Only', 'dingit.tv', '1019807', '359', '0.04', 'OK'], ['Real Site', 'hgtv.com', '6478', '274', '4.23', 'OK'], ['Real Site', 'mail.yahoo.com', '408744', '240', '0.06', 'OK'], ['Real Site', 'firstrowsportes.net', '211061', '238', '0.11', 'OK'], ['Real Site', 'tpc.googlesyndication.com', '314740', '232', '0.07', 'OK'], ['Real Site', 'bitlanders.com', '21827', '229', '1.05', 'OK'], ['Real Site', 'go.rivosport.co', '326261', '224', '0.07', 'OK'], ['Real Site', 'myasiantv.se', '100480', '220', '0.22', 'OK'], ['Real Site', 'firstrows.xyz', '145247', '218', '0.15', 'OK'], ['Real Site', 'streaming-foot.xyz', '204521', '200', '0.1', 'OK'], ['Real Site', 'start.att.net', '250292', '180', '0.07', 'OK'], ['Real Site', 'myp1p.eu', '30250', '155', '0.51', 'OK'], ['Real Site', 'spotify.com', '15037', '139', '0.92', 'OK'], ['Real Site', 'nflstream.net', '121400', '129', '0.11', 'OK'], ['Real Site', 'metoffice.gov.uk', '69592', '93', '0.13', 'OK']]
```

Comment: Te etiqueto @FJSevilla

Comment: Gracias @Mariano!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes iterar con un `for` como comentas sobre la lista de listas pero debes obtener cada elemento mediante indexación (en este caso la columna `ddomain` tiene el índice 1, recordando que se indexa desde 0). Usa una lista por compresión:

```
ddomain = [row[1] for row in your_list]
```

Si solo te interesa esta columna no crees la lista intermedia, itera directamente sobre las filas:

```
with open("Top20_Media_10-12-17.csv", 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    ddomain = [row[1] for row in reader]
```

Con pandas también es muy simple usando el método `to_list` de las series:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Top20_Media_10-12-17.csv")
ddomain = df['ddomain'].tolist()
```

En todos los casos obtendrás como primer elemento el nombre de la columna ("ddomain"), si no lo quieres, para eliminarlo puedes simplemente hacer:

```
del(ddomain[0])
```

Comment: `import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Top20_Media_10-12-17.csv")
ddomain = df['ddomain'].tolist()` tengo error con eso: pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file

Comment: O tienes un csv inválido por alguna razón o un delimitador distinto de la coma o problemas con la codificación que usas en tu csv, por ejemplo UTF-8 con BOM da este problema. Sin tener acceso al archivo csv es difícil dar con la causa.